# Omitting patterns in regex

Tags: php, regex

I am writing a regex pattern that will exclude two patterns in order to create clickable links on a page;

```
$message = preg_replace("#(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)(?!img.youtube.com/vi/)[-a-zA-Z?-??-?()0-9@:%_+.~\#?&;//=,]+)#i", "<a href=$1 target='_blank'><b>$1</b></a>", $message);
```

The first pattern, (?!img.youtube.com/vi/), seems to work just fine - if this pattern is found in $message, it skips over it.  The second pattern I'm having trouble with.  I do not want this regex to apply to patterns with .jpg, .gif, and .bmp extensions (so, http://dfjrnen.com/fjejfj.jpg.  I have another regex that handles these kinds of strings and would like for the one above to not affect it.

So, it seems that if I want to do this that I should set something up like this;

```
$message = preg_replace("#(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)(?!img.youtube.com/vi/)[-a-zA-Z?-??-?()0-9@:%_+.~\#?&;//=,]?!(\.jpg|\.gif|\.bmp)+)#i", "<a href=$1 target='_blank'><b>$1</b></a>", $message);
```

This does not seem to work.  Can someone point out the issue?

Comment: See the explanation of negative lookahead here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Okay, but where does negative look ahead go in the regex above?  After the + ?  Before?  Some context or detail would be helpful.

Comment: It goes at the place where the suffix would be found in strings you don't want to match.

Comment: So, like this? $message = preg_replace("#(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)(?!img.youtube.com/vi/)[-a-zA-Z?-??-?()0-9@:%_+.~\#?&;//=,]?!(\.jpg))#i", 
"<a href=$1 target='_blank'><b>$1</b></a>", $message);

Comment: That's really hard to read without formatting. But `?!` has to be after the parenthesis that starts the group. Read the documentation again.

Comment: Okay, so let me just say thank you for trying to help me, I do appreciate it, but you must understand that the link you sent me does not help someone who's trying to understand the problem from zero.  I don't understand what you mean when you say " But ?! has to be after the parenthesis that starts the group." What group are you referring to?  The regex, as it is, has an example of lookaround in the youtube part "(?!img.youtube.com/vi/)".  It sounds reasonable to think that if I'm trying to ommit on more pattern, it would work similarly.  I've tried adding in several spots but it doesnt work.

Comment: Groups are the things that are inside parentheses in regular expressions. So it should be `(?!\.jpg)`, not `!?(\.jpg)`.

Comment: Please put backticks around pieces of code in your comments so they format properly.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds to me that it should look like this?    \$message = preg_replace("#(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)(?!img.youtube.com/vi/)(?!(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.bmp))[-a-zA-Z?-??-?()0-9@:%_+.~\#?&;//=,]+)#i", 
"<a href=$1 target='_blank'><b>$1</b></a>", $message);\  The backticks dont seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$legal = '-a-zA-Z()0-9@:%_+.~\#?&;/=,';
$regex = "#((f|ht)tps?://(?!img.youtube.com/vi/)[$legal]+)" .
         "(?<!\.jpg|\.gif|\.bmp)(?<!\.jpeg)(?![$legal])#i";
$replace = "<a href=$1 target='_blank'><b>$1</b></a>";
$message = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $message);
```

- I put the allowed URL characters in `$legal`, because they are needed twice in the pattern and we don't want to write them duplicated.
- Since we want to exclude URLs with certain extensions, which appear at the end of the URL, we can use *negative lookbehind* `(?<!...)` **after** the URL pattern. I use two separate lookbehinds for the extensions of different lenghts - otherwise PHP would complain:

```
    preg_replace(): Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length
```

- But the lookbehinds alone won't do - they just cause the match to be shortened, i. e. instead of `http://dfjrnen.com/fjejfj.jpg` the match would be `http://dfjrnen.com/fjejfj.jp`. To exclude the whole match in such case, we can check that the following character indeed is not part of a URL by using the *negative lookahead* `(?![$legal])`.